# Merits of smaller less verbose keyboards for phones/mobile devices

Tags: mobile, android, ios, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Are there any merits to using a smaller and or possibly less verbose keyboard on mobile devices in certain scenarios?

I was thinking possibly changing keyboards for logins or other areas where you might only have a small subset of characters.

I know there is extensive research about the smallest sized touch buttons (Apple , Google, Motorola , Microsoft all have guides on this) , but what I am asking is what about putting say p/o on the same button or using the keyboards of the 9 button phones on screen.

Are there any instances where it would be wise to show a non traditional keyboard on the screen? (I am aware of the split keyboards but I am talking phones, and novel layouts of the keys / eliminating certain things.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most users hate typing on mobile. See  [Mobile Usability](http://www.nngroup.com/books/mobile-usability/)

That being said, you should make typing as comfortable as possible. I would not go and change the expected behavior by switching the keyboards *unless it helps preventing critical errors*.

Almost all devices offer context-sensitive keyboards. These will e.g. display digits if it's a digit-only field and prevent the user from entering forbidden characters.

The user might also have installed a different keyboard, so who are you to force him to use *yours*? ;-)

Comment: users cant install different keyboards so far on iOS. its a borderline "security" feature apple says

Comment: @Bob that's true, but you also tagged your question with "android". it wasn't my main point anyway.

Comment: your right totally forgot